# Changed React website to java website on same domain but still displays react website

Tags: java, reactjs, heroku

**Environments:**

**Old Website:** React hosted on Heroku URL(http://sameurl.com)

**New Website:** Java hosted on Heroku URL(http://sameurl.com) but on a new heroku account

I had previously react website running on my domain URL, but now I have hosted Java  with AngularJS website on same URL but on a new heroku account.

But when I load the URL in browser I see the old react website, after clearing cache I am able to see the newer Java website. But this is very big issue for me as the clients of this website still see the older website content, as they have not cleared their browser cache. And we can not tell them to do so.

I guess there must be any way to achieve this from server side.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The answer here would be that the react website would not be configured with proper caching headers or with Caching header having a larger age on them. This is the reason why the browser is validating the cache and it still finds it valid.

Configuring the response header on your server with the new Java hosted website may resolve the issue. But they are possibly users who still have to clear the cache in order to load the new website. You can have a look at this [article](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching) from Google to understanding caching and making caching more effective.